# rails encoding issue =(

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i use rails 2.3.9 with ruby 1.9.2 and when i trying to update my model with some russian letters i have error in unicorn log:

```
Error during failsafe response: incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
Read error: #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
```

trace look like this:

> /home/rbdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/unicorn-3.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:521:in
>   `process_client'
>   /home/rbdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/unicorn-3.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:594:in`
>   block in worker_loop'
>   /home/rbdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/unicorn-3.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:592:in
>   `each'
>   /home/rbdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/unicorn-3.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:592:in`
>   worker_loop'
>   /home/rbdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/unicorn-3.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:482:in
>   `block (2 levels) in
>   spawn_missing_workers'
>   /home/rbdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/unicorn-3.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:479:in`
>   fork'
>   /home/rbdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/unicorn-3.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:479:in
>   `block in spawn_missing_workers'
>   /home/rbdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/unicorn-3.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:475:in`
>   each'
>   /home/rbdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/unicorn-3.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:475:in
>   `spawn_missing_workers'
>   /home/rbdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/unicorn-3.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:489:in`
>   maintain_worker_count'
>   /home/rbdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/unicorn-3.0.1/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:299:in
>   `join'
>   /home/rbdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/unicorn-3.0.1/lib/unicorn.rb:13:in`
>   run'
>   /home/rbdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/gems/unicorn-3.0.1/bin/unicorn_rails:208:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>   /home/rbdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/bin/unicorn_rails:19:in`
>   load'
>   /home/rbdev/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@rails2/bin/unicorn_rails:19:in
>   `'

so, i can't detirminate the problem, the only thing i know - what problem in russia text ( when i update model with english letters - all is ok. what i can do ? (

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure that your editor saves files in UTF-8. ASCII afaik is the first part of any charset. That should be the reason you don't get any errors when you leave out the russian chars.

Comment: rbdev@Ubuntu-1004-lucid-64-minimal:~/sites/avantage/app/views/admin/categories$ file -i edit.html.haml 
edit.html.haml: text/plain; charset=us-ascii

Answer (score 1):

I answered this one here, with a script.  [Why are all strings ASCII-8BIT after I upgraded to Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999415/why-are-all-strings-ascii-8bit-after-i-upgraded-to-rails-3/4158423#4158423)

You need

```
# coding: UTF-8
```

at the top of your files, with ruby 1.9. If that doesn't help, it might be your external dependency, such as DB.

Answer (score 0):

you can use gem "russian" (gem is based on l18n)
https://github.com/yaroslav/russian
in model (instead of russian letters): 
    Russian::translate(:some_word)

in config file (must be encoded in UTF-8): 
    ru:
      some_word: 'это строка с русскими буквами (this is string with russian letters)'