# Add "# coding: utf-8" to all files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, utf-8

Can I somehow configure Rails to avoid the need to add `# coding: utf-8` to all files? Or must I add it to each file manually?

**UPD**

To improve my life I have found this gem:

> [magic_encoding](https://rubygems.org/gems/magic_encoding)

It won't fix the problem, but it will add magick line to each file. Related topic: [Why are all strings ASCII-8BIT after I upgraded to Rails 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3999415/why-are-all-strings-ascii-8bit-after-i-upgraded-to-rails-3/4158423#4158423)

Comment: nope, only `magic_encoding gem`

Comment: don't you mean # encoding: utf-8 ? From what I read, you can't avoid it, but you can configure your IDE to add this line by default to new .rb files or use the magic_encoding gem from time to time.

Answer (score 3):

In a rails application you can specify the default chracter encoding in your application config.

Add the following code inside the `Application` class in in `config/application.rb`

Looks something like:

```
# Configure the default encoding used in templates for Ruby 1.9.
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

Comment: Yep, that is default encoding which is not exactly about the issue. YOu still need to define encoding in each file.

Comment: it does not prevent apache/passenger to horribly fail when you forgot one `# encoding: UTF-8`