# invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII) MAC OSX RUBY on Rails Without magic enconding?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, character-encoding

On ruby 1.8.7 I had no problems with swedish chars ÅÄÖ but now on ruby 1.9.2 this exception comes up. Strangley enough it does not appear on my Ubuntu machine.

Can it be fixed without Magic encoding or putting #encoding utf-8 on top of every ruby file with Swedish chars?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no solution to avoid this Error without adding encoding line

> [Add "# coding: utf-8" to all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037094/add-coding-utf-8-to-all-files)

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, try to add this

```
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

to your ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile or equivalent. It worked here!