# Encoding error while writing data from excelfile to database (mysql)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, utf-8, import-from-excel

I get this error when writing to database:

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError "\xD0" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

After googling around a bit the problem seems to lie in ruby 1.9.2 string handling but no real solution found.

I use magic_encoding to force utf-8 on all data. My database runs on utf-8 as well.

I'm running rails 3.1 and ruby 1.9.2.

Anyone that can shine some light on this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add this line to the top of your .rb file

```
# encoding: utf-8
```

Or you can use this gem

> [magic_encoding](https://rubygems.org/gems/magic_encoding)

Related topic:

> [Add "# coding: utf-8" to all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037094/add-coding-utf-8-to-all-files)

Comment: I use magic_encoding and I tried coding and encoding with no success. Any other suggestions?

Comment: that's weird. What the name of the file you are executing in this proces? Is that a rake task or just a model, or custom class or what?

Comment: I read an excelfile and write down the content from a model class.

Comment: def upload_file(params)
  uploaded_io = params[:upload][:excelfile]
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploadedfiles', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'w') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end
end

Comment: In my very similar case adding `encoding` line fixes this problem. Last try: did you restart your app server?

Comment: I found a solution. I used the method force_encoding and it magically worked.