# How to set #encoding: utf-8 in Rails globally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding

now i'm using `# encoding: utf-8` in every controller, where :notice message is not in *latin*
i've tried to put it in ApplicationController, tried to add `<meta charset="utf-8">` at the top of application.html.erb, none worked, any help ?

**EDIT:**
config.encoding = "utf-8" also set in **application.rb**

**EDIT:**

error appears with this code:

```
redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Вышли успешно"
```

and here's an error

```
:syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting '}' ..._or_to root_url, :notice => 'Вышли успешно.' }
```

Comment: As far as I know Rails automatically uses UTF-8. What's your exact problem? How does the not UTF-8 part show?

Comment: error appears with this code:

Comment: possible duplicate of [Add "# coding: utf-8" to all files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037094/add-coding-utf-8-to-all-files)

Comment: the solution which is offered there is not working either

Comment: here is no general solution. you can't set it globally

Comment: You could patch the ruby interpreter ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a duplicate of [Set global default encoding for ruby 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908774/set-global-default-encoding-for-ruby-1-9), but in your case I suggest using the `I18n`:

```
redirect_to root_url, :notice => I18n.t 'sessions.destroy.success'

# config/locales/ru.yml
ru:
  sessions:
    destroy:
      success: Вышли успешно
```

As for locales key naming, AFAIK there's no convention, here I use "controller_name.action_name.result" scheme.