# ActiveRecord Query Failing For Name Containing Accented Characters

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord, unicode, special-characters

I have a Rails app using Postgres. I have a `Document` model that has a `name` attribute. Some names contain accented characters. A couple of example names:

> Condições Para Aplicação Da Lei
>
> Considerações Introdutórias

I am querying for models with a specific name using:

```
document = Document.where(name: "Example Document Name").first
```

So long as the name doesn't contain special characters, this works fine, however as soon as I use a name containing any accented characters, the query returns nil.

```
$ Document.all
$ #<Document id: 1, name: "Foo" ... >
$ #<Document id: 1, name: "Considerações Introdutórias" ... >
$ Document.where(name: "Foo").first
$ #<Document id: 1, name: "Foo" ... > 
$ Document.where(name: "Considerações Introdutórias").first
$ # nil
```

**Why is this query failing when the name contains special characters?**

In my `config/application.rb`:

```
config.encoding = "utf-8"
```

In my `config/database.yml':

```
encoding: utf8
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your utf configuration.
 `config.encoding = "utf-8"`

check in database.yml for `encoding: utf8`.

See these questions

[Add "# coding: utf-8" to all files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7037094/add-coding-utf-8-to-all-files)

[Set global default encoding for ruby 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5908774/set-global-default-encoding-for-ruby-1-9)

Comment: Thanks. Good advice (updated question with settings), but the problem lay elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem wasn't with Rails, but with OSX. There are different ways of representing the same characters; either as a single symbol, or decomposed into multiple components. Both versions are displayed identically in the Terminal, but copy the names into a  plain text file and you will see the difference:

Composed:

```
Considerações Introdutórias
```

Decomposed *(I can only get the decomposed version to display in here by adding spaces around the decomposed characters)*:

```
Condic ̧ o ̃ es Para Aplicac ̧ a ̃ o Da Lei
```

In order to fix the mismatch, I used [Unicode Utils](https://github.com/lang/unicode_utils) to compose the filenames before adding them to the database and again before using them to search:

```
require "unicode_utils/nfc"

...

filename = UnicodeUtils.nfc(filename)
```